# Can I pass non-URL definition view keyword to a view function when redirecting?

Tags: django, django-urls

```
NoReverseMatch at /natrium/script/4c55be7f74312bfd435e4f672e83f44374a046a6aa08729aad6b0b1ab84a8274/

Reverse for 'run_details' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'script_text': u'print "happy"', 'run_id': '6b2f9127071968c099673254fb3efbaf'}' not found.
```

This is an ***excerpt*** of my views.py

```
run_id = new_run.run_id
if not run_id:
raise AssertionError("bad run id")

# I tried with args=[run_id, clean['script_text']] too
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('run_details', kwargs={'run_id':run_id, 'script_text':clean['script_text']}))
```

which in turns calling this view function

```
def run_details(request, run_id, script_text):
    """
    Displays the details of a given run.
    """
    run = Run(run_id)
    run.update(request.user)

    codebundle = CodeBundle(run.cbid)
    codebundle.update(request.user)

    return render_response(request, "graphyte/runs/run_script.html",
                           {'run':run, 'codebundle':codebundle, 'files':run.artifacts, 'bundle':codebundle,
                            'source_code': script_text
                           })
```

Now this is my urls.py. The actual redirect views is in another app (kinda insane, but whatever...).

```
urlpatterns = patterns("webclient.apps.codebundles.views",
    # many.....
    url(r"^cb/newfolder/$", 'codebundle_newfolder', name="codebundle_newfolder"),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('webclient.apps.runs.views',
        url(r"^run_details/(?P<run_id>\w+)/$", 'run_details', name="run_details"),)
```

This is getting really nasty for the last three hours. I am not sure what's going on. Can someone help me debug this?

Thanks.

---

The original plan did not have script_text, and I used args=['run_id'] only. It works. In other words, remove script_text from the two views everything will work.

---

**EDIT**
Sorry for the confusion. Script text is just a context variable that I need to pass to the reverse destination, and from there I render my template. The URLs should only display the run_id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't really pass an 'extra keyword' to the view function when redirecting. I'll try to explain why.

When you return `HttpResponseRedirect`, Django returns a response with a 302 status code, and the new location.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.example.com/new-url/
```

Your browser will then usually fetch the new url, but that's a separate request. If your view needs a keyword, it needs to be included in that response somehow, unless you store state in the session. Your two options are

1. Include the extra keyword in the url:

   `http://www.example.com/new-url/keyword-value/`
2. Include the extra keyword as a GET parameter

   `http://www.example.com/new-url/?keyword=keyword-value.`

   Then in your view, grab the keyword with `keyword=request.GET['keyword']`. Note that the keyword is no longer a kwarg in the view signature.

A third approach is to stick the keyword into the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views) before you redirect, then grab it out the session in the redirected view. I would advise against doing this because it's stateful and can cause odd results when users refresh pages etc.

Comment: Thank you for the detail explaintion. It's 4 in the morning so I am not getting any sleep :( sorry for the mess. script_text is a string of source code. So it isn't fesiable to put it in the urls. Session might be a workaround (the equvialent of gloabl variable, which is what I am using now for test).

Answer (score 1):

Your `run_details` url doesn't accept a `kwarg` named `script_text` at all -- remove that from your reverse kwargs.

Comment: Right. My bad. I just edited my post. The original plan did not have script_text. Is it because the url only reads in the capture keyword? Is it even possible to throw keywords at view functions that are not going to be captured?

Comment: You can certainly send kwargs to a view function (for example, as the third argument to a url definition) but you can't reverse a url for a non existent combination of kwargs. With `reverse`, you're telling django: "Hey, give me a URL that accepts exactly these arguments and these kwargs".

Comment: I think a reason to use reverse is to make things more "modular". I can certinaly throw in the run_details stuff into the first virews, and render template from there. Bear with me. Are you sayign that with **reverse** I cannot throw in kwargs that are not part of the urls definition (http://mysite.com/natrium/run_details/run_id/) ? Thanks.

Comment: @CppLearner, the example you linked is confusing - run_id is valid. Your URL captures one keyword argument `run_id` and zero arguments. That is the single parameter that can be used to identify a final URL for this url pattern.

Comment: Thank you. script_text is just a template context variable that I must passed to the reverse destination. Over there, I render template. Question is, can it be done?

Comment: @CppLearner, you can use a get request or session variable. reverse_url?fo=bar