# Django render redirect to page with changing url

Tags: python, html, django, url, web

I am creating a custom login for my django application and problem occurs when i click `logout` on template I programmed it so it go to index page but the url in the browser remains `http://127.0.0.1:8000/logout/` even reaching index page. I want it to become `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` .

views.py

```
def logout(request):
    try:
        del request.session['uid']
        return render(request, 'home.html')
    except:
        pass
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def home_page(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

template

```
 <p>
    Publisher Dashboard, Welcome {{ user.name }}.
    <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Logout</a>
</p>
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from mainapp import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.home_page, name='homepage'),
url(r'^registration/$', views.signup_user, name='signup_user'),
....
url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, name='logout'),
]
```

Comment: Django has a [built in authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/). You should use this if at all possible, rather than rolling your own system that uses `session['uid']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are rendering the `'home.html` template, instead of redirecting the user to the homepage.

If you want to redirect then you should return an `HttpResponseRedirect` response, or use the `redirect` shortcut.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def logout(request):
    ...
    return redirect('/')
```

Comment: can i use `redirect()` to send some value from views.py to template as `redirect('/', { 'user': user  })`  ? @Alasdair

Comment: No. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999636/can-i-pass-non-url-definition-view-keyword-to-a-view-function-when-redirecting/9000663#9000663).

Comment: Thanks for help. @Alasdair

Answer (score 0):

**Render** will give a new webpage but not a new URL.

**Redirect** will give a new URL.

So in case of render, your address bar will not change though a new web page will be loaded.
But in case of new URL, you are actually getting a new URL and therefore a new webpage for that URL with address bar updated.